# Recovery text data from a NTFS partition after disk checking

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ntfs, file-recovery, textfiles

I have a Win 7 laptop.

Today, when I have started Windows, it asked me for checking the partition `F:` on my hard drive. I accepted. It shows the message that it will delete invalid entries. And stopped checkdisk quickly.

I enter Windows and my `F:` partition is still there but all the files are gone.

In this partition I have saved all my works, projects including source code text file such as `*.java`, `*.c`, etc.

I keep it unchanged (do nothing on this partition). **What can I do now to restore my data?** Also the data recovery tool just recovered images, videos, ... But not text files as I have.

Comment: which data recovery tool did you used?

Comment: I have try Recuva, and UnChk ...

Comment: could you please try Getdataback for ntfs/fat, I got most of my lost files using this software.for better result, install this software on another machine and attach the disk to be recovered to that machine and then try to recover

Comment: Well, Recuva should also work when you search for all files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good to hear from you that [Getdataback for NTFS/FAT](http://www.runtime.org/data-recovery-software.htm) helped you to recover files.Another remarkable software is the [EaseUS recover tool](http://www.easeus.com/datarecovery/)